# Laravel: apiResouce route not found issue

Tags: laravel, api, http-status-code-404

In my laravel application I am using `apiResponse` for routes. But, while making an api request I am getting `404 not found` error. Here is an example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
    /**
     * Categories
     */
    Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'categories' ], function() {
        Route::apiResource('/', 'v1\CategoryController')->except(['destroy', 'show']);

        Route::get('/edit/{category}', 'v1\CategoryController@edit');
        // Route::patch('/{category}', 'v1\CategoryController@update');
        Route::patch('/status/{category}/{status}', 'v1\CategoryController@status');
    });
});
```

[image]

When I am accessing the `update` api via `patch` method it returns `404 not found`

**CategoryController.php**

```
...

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\ApiModels\v1\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function update(Request $Request, $category)
    {
        # models
        $Category = new Category();

        # accessing methods
        if(($querySubmit = $Category->update($Request->all(), $category))['success'] == false)
        {
            return $this->response([
                'class' => 'alert-danger'
            ], false, $this->parentErrors($querySubmit));
        }

        return $this->response([], true, 'Category has been saved successfully.');
    }

    ...
}
```

However, if I un-comment the `patch` method for the `update` route then it starts working. Because it starts using the new route, completely ignoring the restful controller route.

I don't want to include the extra code, specially for the same functionality which laravel has already given.

How to fix this issue...?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resource` and `apiResource` methods are for resources. You are not passing in the name of a resource, which is technically what should be passed into them, or a URI ending in a resource name. You probably want to something like this instead:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'v1'], function() {
    Route::patch('categories/{category}/{status}', 'CategoryController@status');

    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController')
        ->except(['destroy', 'show', 'create']);
});
```

Then your routes would be:

```
GET         api/v1/categories                      index
POST        api/v1/categories                      store
GET         api/v1/categories/{category}/edit      edit
PUT/PATCH   api/v1/categories/{category}           update
```

The fact you want the `edit` route means you probably want to use `resource` instead of `apiResource` and just exclude the ones you don't want